# Standard equivalent for Intel Fortran form = 'binary'

Tags: file-io, fortran, binaryfiles, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have a problem with a Fortran code that is written for compiling with Intel Fortran compiler.

The specific problem I have is with the `OPEN` statement. I tried to rewrite the source code so I can compile it with a free compiler, namely GNU Fortran, and I succeeded, but I have some issues with it.

There is some temporary file output with `OPEN(access = 'direct', form = 'binary', status = 'replace'...)`, but `form = 'binary'` is not standard and not supported by GNU Fortran compiler.

After looking for solutions on the web I found that `form = 'unformatted'` should be equivalent and GNU Fortran can deal with it. Yes, it is true, I was able to compile and the code runs correctly. However, the code is a scientific calculation generating a huge amount of data in these files opened this way. My problem is that `form = 'unformatted'` results in files 4 times bigger than with `form = 'binary'`.

With this I do not have enough hard disk space for successful runs in some cases with unformatted format, while with binary I could have. Is there an equivalent for Intel Fortran's 'binary' that can be used with GNU Fortran and results in similar file sizes?

As it was asked for, I am adding a short, simplified sample code:

```
subroutine init
use module params  ! contains param1, param2, param3, ... which are inetger or real
common /params2/ maxi, maxj, maxk, limit, recnum ! integers defined elsewhere
real*8, allocatable :: x(:)
... other variables
open (unit = 5, file = 'data.txt', access = 'direct',
 *    form = 'binary', recl = 16*maxk+8, status = 'replace')
write(5, rec = 1) param1, param2, param3, maxi, maxj, maxk, limit, recnum ...
recnum = 2
do i = 1, maxi
  do j = 2, maxj
     ... do some stuff with x
     write(55, rec=recnum) x(0), (xt(k), xt(limit-k), k = 1, maxk)
  recnum = recnum + 1
  done
done
close(5)
end subroutine init

program xx
common /params2/ maxi, maxj, maxk, limit, recnum
...
call subroutine init
...
open (unit = 5, file = 'data.txt', access = 'direct',
 *   form = 'binary', recl = 16*maxk+8, status = 'old')
... do some stuff
read(5, rec=1) param1, param2, param3, maxi, maxj, maxk, limit, recnum, ...
... do some stuff
recnum = 1
do i = 1, maxi
  do j = 2, maxj
  recnum = recnum + 1
     ... do some stuff
     read(5, rec=recnum) x(0), (xt(k), xt(limit-k), k = 1, maxk)
     ... do some stuff
  done
done
close(5)
end program
```

The reading of first record is necessary in `program xx` because the file `data.txt` generated by
`subroutine init` my originate from a previous run (call of `subroutine init` might not happen at every run),
and some parameters are needed to be read to interpret data in `data.txt`.

Multiple files are generated like this and the first record is not always needed.
I assume `access = stream` might work if the first record is read even if it is not necessary.

But when I replace `access = direct` with `access = stream` and remove `recl` and every occurrence of `rec =` in `WRITE()` or `READ()` I get runtime error of inconsistency during file I/O.

Comment: Are you saving the same data type in both calls? Can you show your code where the actual writes are being done?

Comment: There is no difference in the two codes except the `binary` vs. `unformatted` exchange. I get the same problem even if I compile both versions with Intel Fortran compiler.

Comment: The bigger file probably arises from the fact that you make many writes and each time you write the GNU compiler adds an integer at the beginning and end that describes the size of the written data. If you provide an `access='stream'` to the `open` statement, you have probably solved your problem.

Comment: I tried it previously, but did not work. Now I had to realize there is an additional aspect important regarding this problem. There is additionally a `recl = ` option for `OPEN`, with a size given on run-time. The writing of data happens record-based, so `write(1, rec=k) a, b, c`, `k` being a variable changed on iteration. But this is incompatible with stream access. With stream access should I just replace `rec=k` with `*` and remove the `recl = ` option from `OPEN`? (It did not work for me...)

Comment: With stream access there are no records and hence no `rec=` and no `recl=`. Optionally there is `pos=` there, but it shouldn't be necessary. You don't show your code so it is hard to say more in detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't able to find an exact duplicate, but has been treated here before.

```
  form='binary'
```

is completely non-standard. The standard way is to use

```
  access='stream', `form='unformatted'
```

that will enable the standard stream access from Fortran 2003 which is modelled after C and can be used in all reasonably recent compilers.

Basically, the `form='binary'` wasn't very compatible with the rest of the language. The right way is to really change the `access`, that's why you are probably confused.

The sequential and direct access are all record-based and can result in record markers being written in addition to your data. The non-standard `form='binary'` changes that, but the proper way is to use the stream access which can be both formatted and unformatted. Especially the unformatted is very handy and let's you save exactly the bytes you have in memory without any additional markers.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I was able to solve with `access = 'stream'` and `form = 'unformatted'`. I had to remove `recl = ` because it is not possible with stream access, and I had to make sure that after every opening a read everything from a file, even if it was specified by direct record reference previously. So selecting a record would only be possible after data is read. The `pos =` option of `stream` could lead to processor/system-dependent accessing, if I am correct, so I avoided that.

Comment: The pos= is dependent on your data sizes. If you fix that it is portable, but you must be sure how many bytes is your real kind, for example.

Comment: you need to also specify `status='replace'` for writing to make it equivalent to `form='binary'` behaviour.

Comment: Status should not really affect this. You shoukd be able to use any `status` and any `action` as needed.